# 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'FILE'

Tags: python, django, excel, file

I want to make an app that takes excel file and reads its content, without using form and models.

I keep getting the error in the title and I would to know what the error is.

This is my HTML:

```
<div style="width: 800px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="." method='POST'> {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="file" name="excelfile">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

This is my view:

```
def uploadexcelfile(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        excel = request.FILE['excelfile'].read()

        print('Opening workbook...')

        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel)
        activesheet = wb.active
        print(activesheet.title)

        sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(activesheet.title)

        print('Reading rows...')
        for row in range(1, sheet.max_row + 1):
            url = sheet['A' + str(row)].value

            print(url)
    else:
        return render(request, 'uploadexcelfile.html')
```

Comment: Did you try `request.FILES['excelfile'].read()` ??

Comment: Sorry! My mistake!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`request.FILES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) instead of `request.FILE`.